# CSS masking or alternatives to achieve a radial focus

Tags: css

[image]

The above image is an idea, lets say I have a fixed dix that covers the page and I want to focus on an area.

```
.fixed-full {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
 }
```

I don't see the above working with what I am trying to accomplish I would need to use a mask or a radial gradient.

I read a few tuts on webkit masking, and svg masking, it's a bit tedious figuring it out, I was hoping to get suggestions.

I played with some box shadow `box-shadow: -20px 30px 380px 280px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;` its an cool effect but not exactly what Id like to have.

Wouldnt mind using a javascript solution.

**CSS Result:** *Thanks to vals* 
[image]

**CSS Result:** *Based on Rémi's approach, thanks*
Looks good but its hard to get a crisp circle, maybe if I fiddle with it :)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired effect with a radial-gradient, e.g. (with a red mask):

```
background: radial-gradient(200px 100px at 100px 50px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .8));
```

as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gmqFe/1/ (nb: text has a yellow background, the mask is red)

To better control the blur region, you can also use pixels instead of percentages for the stop position (above, 40%), then only the ratio of the first two parameters matter, e.g.:

```
background: radial-gradient(10px 5px at 100px 50px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 200px, rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) 202px);
```

Comment: and a link to more documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient#Examples

Comment: This is cool, but there is too much blur, I cant tweak it so that its a pure circle.

Comment: you can actually http://jsfiddle.net/gmqFe/2/ (see the 40% and 45%) (feel free to put 40% 40% if you really want no blur)

Comment: Cool 1+ but It's not a smooth circle, the edges are a bit choppy. I do however like the positioning of the circle its much eaiser than using margin like vals approach. Pros and cons of both.. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gmqFe/4/ it's yours but you can see how easy it is to center the circle..

Comment: Wow yeah this is definitely a method to consider.. I genuinely like both, let me play around and see what fits what I am trying to accomplish better. If I could vote both I would.

Comment: One caveat, is that it doesnt transition with changing the position of the circle, which would be nice. Ill continue to test, maybe I can get it to work with transitions I may google some stuff, but any idea on transitioning the circle would be cool.

Comment: Playing with background-position works with the transition, I need to really study radial gradients to get a much better grasp, but overall this works very well for me. I tried getting into the radial gradient earlier but it seemed like a lot of reading and testing. Now that I have working code I am more motivated to learn more about it.. THANKS, also big thanks to vals your method was good as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that more easily

CSS

```
.mask {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
border-radius: 50%;
width: 116px;
height: 116px;
left: 29px;
top: 61px;
border-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
border-width: 500px;
margin: -500px;
border-style: solid;
}
```

You just set the div with border-radius so that it is a circle, and background-color is the more transparent color in the circle. Then set a big border (I used 500px, you can go higher if you need to). To make positioning easy, set the same amount as a negative margin. And set the border color to whatever you want.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STrCA/)

If you want to make it easier to go to a determinate point in the screen, you can make the margin compansate fully the margin and the size. For instance

```
border-width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin: -1050px;
```

The margin compensates the border and half the size, so setting top = y left = x will set the circle to be around x y

Comment: Hey never thought about something like this.. thanks let me try it.

Comment: This is nice, thanks. Id like to understand some math behind this, what would be the best way to get the border to be 100%, and on top of that what would be a good solution to pinpointing a place on the page so that its consistent with all screen sizes. I applied it to my project and looks good (screen shot above). I just want to make it consistent.

Comment: I have added another math to get the circle where you want easier.

Comment: Thanks so much.. itll be nice throwing a transition on it and using it as a tour modal. Being able to calculate it more efficiently will allow me to add a class based on what I want to show. Okay I see now.